# How to configure cover for a node with multliple applications

Tags: erlang, cover, common-test

I have 4 applications within a node, all tested with Common Test.

My cover specification:

```
{level, details}.
{incl_dirs, ["apps/app1/ebin", "apps/app2/ebin", "apps/app3/ebin", "apps/app4/ebin"]}.
```

Test command:

```
ct_run -pa apps/*/ebin -pa deps/*/ebin -dir apps/*/test/ -logdir tests -cover cover.spec
```

The problem is that cover report (html) for each application contains all modules from other apps as well, which obviously have 0% coverage. Is there a way to configure it to exclude modules which do not belong to given app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [cover configuration documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/cover_chapter.html), it doesn't seem like you can exclude by application.  However, you can use the `{excl_dirs_r, Dirs}.` option to exclude a directory if the dependencies are contained in a single tree.  Alternatively, you can use `{incl_mods, Mods}.` to only cover the modules you are interested in.  I've used this second approach, and it works for me.  You can write a script to collect the names of all the modules in your own applications.

Comment: i like second approach!!